# Random variable deterministic if sigma algebra trivial

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I am struggling with this problem for days and would be great to have your help. The problem is below:

"Let $X$ be a random variable. Prove the following statements:

(a) $\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ iff $X$ is constant.

(b) If $X\sim \delta_c$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $P(E) \in \{0,1\},  \forall E\in\sigma(X)$.

(c) If $P(E) \in \{0,1\}, \forall E\in\sigma(X)$, then $X\sim\delta_c$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$. (Hint: Analyze the distribution function of F).

As a result, we can see that $X$ is deterministic iff $\sigma(X)$ is trivial."

Where $\delta_c$ is the Dirac measure.

I more or less have an idea for part (a), however, parts (b) and (c) are more complicated for me. Any advice on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b): You should know that every $E \in \sigma(X)$ is of the form $E = X^{-1}(B)$ for some Borel set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$.  Then $P(E) = \delta_c(B)$ by definition of $\sim$.

(c): The hint is a good one.  If $F$ is the distribution function of $X$, so that $F(x) = P(X \le x)$, then the assumption implies that $F$ only takes the values 0 and 1.  You also know that $F$ is monotone increasing, so what must it look like?  This will help you find the value of $c$.

(By the way, $c$ is poorly worded; it should say "... then there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $X \sim \delta_c$".)